# While accessing a php script in my localhost through an android application I get an unexpected end of stream on Connection{192.168.43.230:25689, ..}

Tags: php, android, http-status-code-403

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://192.168.43.230:25689/test/login.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); 
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Append parameters to URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Open connection for sending data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            return e1.getMessage();
            //return "exception";
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return(result.toString());

            }else{
                return Integer.toString(response_code);
                //return("unsuccessful");
            }
```

I am trying to run a php script(wamp server) from my android application on my mobile. I connected the mobile and my computer to the same network.

The response code shows 403.I disabled the firewall and added the useragent also.

Can anyone tell what the possibility for the error is.

Comment: What happens when you replace the php code with some simple static HTML? What happens when you try to open the URL in the browser on android?

Comment: Even if I replace the php with html file, the error is still the same. @NineBerry

Comment: And what happens when you try to open the URL in the browser app on android?

Comment: Forbidden-You don't have permission to test

Comment: What happens when you try to open the URL in a browser on the computer where wamp is installed?

Comment: It works fine then

Comment: Well, then this seems to be a problem with the wamp configuration with regard to allowing access from different computers, not a programming question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137240/discussion-between-jab-and-nineberry).

Answer (score 2):

Well, since the HTTP response code is 403 is means that access is denied, it means the problem is more than likely on the web server end. A couple of things you can check is if the web server has access/permissions to retrieve the file(s) you're trying to access.

Also check if the route to your login.php is configured to be accessible in your webserver configs.

Comment: How to check if my web server has permissions?

Comment: Since it looks like you're using an Apache server. There should be a couple of log files that'll give you a better idea of what's going on. It looks like there should be a log folder where you have your WAMP installation installed, if so look inside the error.log and maybe access.log, there should at least give you an idea of what's happening.